# How could I use alias in xargs

Tags: shell, zsh

Ubuntu uses zsh, now have an `alias`

```
alias | grep sayhi
sayhi='echo hi'

sayhi foo
hi foo
```

However, I can't use this `alias` in `xargs` or bash, see below

```
➜  ~  echo foo | xargs -i sayhi {}
xargs: sayhi: No such file or directory
➜  ~  echo foo | awk '{print "sayhi "$0}'
sayhi foo
➜  ~  echo foo | awk '{print "sayhi "$0}'|bash
bash: line 1: sayhi: command not found
```

It seems I can't use `alias` indirectly in command line.

So how could I use `alias` in this situation?

Comment: How about using a "while read"?

Comment: Global alias. But that's a pretty horrific thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Leaving aside the fact that you're dealing with *two different shells*:

- `xargs` can only invoke *external utilities* (executables), so by definition it can't invoke an alias (directly).
- Piping to `bash` will run in a *child* process that is unaware of your current shell's aliases (and non-interactive Bash instances will neither read the usual profile / initialization files nor expand aliases by default).

While you *could* make it work with many contortions that significantly complicate invocation, your best bet is convert your alias to a *script* and have `xargs` / `bash` invoke that.

To get the same single-word invocation experience as with an alias:

- create script `sayhi` (without a filename suffix); example content, taken from your follow-up question:

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  echo hi $@
  ```
- make it *directly* executable: `chmod +x sayhi` - that way you don't have to involve a shell executable to invoke it.
- place it in a directory listed in your `$PATH` variable.

You will then be able to invoke your script like any other executable in your path - by filename only - and the sample commands from your question should work.

Comment: Thanks, but please see my below answer